# How can I get the serializer-fields in APIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I get the  [serializer-fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields)  in APIView?

In the document, it only say how to add serializer-fields in serializers, but did not state how to get the serializer-fields in the  APIView.

I add so many `serializer-fields` in the `CloudServerCreateSerializer`:

```
class CloudServerCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    cpu = serializers.IntegerField()  # eg:1,2,4,
    ram = serializers.IntegerField()  # eg: 1,2,4,
    os = serializers.DictField()  # eg: {"os_big":"Linux", "os_detail":"CentOS7.2"}

    disk_os = serializers.DictField()  # {"disk_type":"SSD", "disk_size":"50"}
    disk_store = serializers.ListField()  # [{"disk_type":"SSD", "disk_size":"50"}, {"disk_type":"SSD", "disk_size":"50"}]

    class Meta:
        model = CloudServer
        exclude = ['expiration_time']
```

but I do not know how to get these values in the views:

```
class CloudServerCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CloudServerCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = CloudServer.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        print(*args, **kwargs)


        #serializer.save()
        return Response(data="创建成功", status=HTTP_200_OK, exception=None)
```

How to get the serializer-fields in rest framework views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing an `APIView` derived class, which is just a basic class based view.  [API Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) are intended to handle the framework tasks of auth, content type negotiation, and so on, leaving all request processing logic to you.  They do not know about `serializer_class` or `queryset`, those are part of the [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

Thankfully, it is quite easy to run the serializer manually and get the data you want.  You can even have it raise 400 errors for you.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ser = CloudServerCreateSerializer(
        data=request.data, 
        context={'request': request}
    )
    ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    data = ser.validated_data
    # use the data somehow
```

Some notes:

- The `context` param contains extra data the serializer can use.  For example, the `request` to use to find the host-name for making url fields.  You may be able to ignore this.
- `is_valid(True)` will raise all serializer errors back to the client, such as 400 or any that you throw.  You don't have to revalidate the data inside afterwards.
- `*ars, **kwargs` will be empty unless your URL specifies path paramters, e.g. `/users/(?<username>\w+)/details/`

If you want to serialize a model to json using this, then you would pass the `instance` parameter:

```
data = MySerializer(instance=MyModel.objects.first()).data
```

If you are trying to make a [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) to fully handle the model (get, create, list, delete, ...), then you want to use `ModelViewSet`

```
class CloudServerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CloudServerCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = CloudServer.objects.all()

 router.register(r'clouds', CloudServerViewSet, base_name='clouds')
 # this will give you
 # POST  /prefix/clouds/      # create
 # GET   /prefix/clouds/      # list
 # GET   /prefix/clonds/:pk/  # details
 # PATCH /prefix/clonds/:pk/  # update
```